# Angularjs with liferay

Tags: angularjs, liferay

I am trying to use angular Js with liferay 6.2. But I am getting error in injecting controller. Same code works well in spring web app. Angular js not compatible with liferay?

> Error : [injector: unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9

Comment: Direct answer: AngularJS *is* compatible with Liferay. "I am getting error"? Well... "You're doing something wrong". What are you doing wrong? How should we know. Show code if you want to fix the problem. And be more specific in the error message that you're getting.

Comment: Getting error while adding controller. Error injector. Unpr

Comment: If that was meant to be an answer to my previous request, you hit enter too early. Please edit your question with the information I've asked for.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you forgot to load the module.

Comment: No i added the module as well. Still i am facing the same error

Comment: like it is suggested up there, It would be helpful if you could show us your code, we can not guess.